# How to invalidate cache between separated createApi() files

Tags: caching, rtk-query

The following code contains many features such as Prompt and Bookmark. I want to create a bookmarkApi file to manage the fetchBookmark, createBookmark, and removeBookmark functions separately.

Even if the code is separated into different files, they cannot share each other's tags, causing an issue where cache invalidation does not occur. How can I fix this?

```
const promptApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "prompts",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: configs.baseUrl,
    }),
    tagTypes: ["Prompt", "Bookmark"],
    endpoints(builder) {
        return {
            fetchPrompts: builder.query({
                query: () => {
                    return {
                        url: "/v1/prompt",
                        method: "GET",
                    };
                },
                providesTags: (result, error, id) => {
                    return result
                        ? [...result.map(({ id }: { id: number }) => ({ type: "Prompt" as const, id })), "Prompt"]
                        : ["Prompt"];
                },
            }),
            fetchPromptDetail: builder.query({
                query: (id) => {
                    return {
                        url: `/v1/prompt/${id}`,
                        method: "GET",
                    };
                },
                providesTags: (result, error, id) => {
                    return [{ type: "Prompt", id }];
                },
            }),
            addQuestion: builder.mutation({
                query: (body) => {
                    return {
                        url: `/v1/prompt/question`,
                        method: "POST",
                        body,
                    };
                },
                invalidatesTags: (result, error, body) => {
                    return [{ type: "Prompt" }];
                },
            }),
            addAnswer: builder.mutation({
                query: (body) => {
                    return {
                        url: `/v1/prompt/answer`,
                        method: "POST",
                        body,
                    };
                },
                invalidatesTags: (result, error, body) => {
                    console.log(body);
                    return [{ type: "Prompt", id: body.promptId }];
                },
            }),
            updatePrompt: builder.mutation({
                query: ({ id, body }) => {
                    return {
                        url: `v1/prompt/${id}`,
                        method: "patch",
                        body,
                    };
                },
                invalidatesTags: (result, error, body) => {
                    return [{ type: "Prompt" }];
                },
            }),
            deletePrompt: builder.mutation({
                query: (id) => {
                    return {
                        url: `v1/prompt/${id}`,
                        method: "delete",
                    };
                },
                invalidatesTags: (result, error, body) => {
                    return [{ type: "Prompt" }];
                },
            }),
            fetchBookmark: builder.query({
                query: (params: { page: number; limit: number }) => {
                    return {
                        url: "/v1/bookmark",
                        method: "GET",
                        params,
                    };
                },
                providesTags: (result, error, id) => {
                    return result
                        ? [
                              ...result.list.map(({ id }: { id: number }) => ({ type: "Bookmark" as const, id })),
                              "Bookmark",
                          ]
                        : ["Bookmark"];
                },
            }),
            createBookmark: builder.mutation({
                query: (body) => {
                    return {
                        url: "/v1/bookmark",
                        method: "POST",
                        body,
                    };
                },
                invalidatesTags: (result, error, body) => {
                    return [{ type: "Prompt" }, { type: "Bookmark" }];
                },
            }),
            removeBookmark: builder.mutation({
                query: (body) => {
                    return {
                        url: `/v1/bookmark/${body.bookmarkId}`,
                        method: "delete",
                    };
                },
                invalidatesTags: (result, error, body) => {
                    return [{ type: "Prompt" }, { type: "Bookmark" }];
                },
            }),
        };
    },
});
```

Comment: This is exactly the reason why the documentation stresses that in 99% of cases you should only have one api for your whole application. Do you have a pressing reason for this to be multiple apis?